# trying to post data to IOT device using PHP

Tags: php, curl, post, lora

I have a thingsuno board. There is one led on the board I want to turn on via a POST request (http integrations) if I do this command in my CLI it works:

```
  curl -i -X POST --data '{"dev_id":"myid","port": 1,"confirmed": false, "payload_raw": "MDA="}' https://integrations.thethingsnetwork.org/ttn-eu/api/v2/down/myapplication/test?key=ttn-account-v2.thekey
```

But now I want to do it in PHP so I have this code:

```
<?php

//API Url
$endpoint_url = 'https://integrations.thethingsnetwork.org/ttn-eu/api/v2/down/myapp/test?key=ttn-account-v2.mykey';


$data_to_post  = [
'dev_id' => 'mydevice',
'port' => 1,
'confirmed' => false,
'payload_raw' => 'MDA='];


$options = [
CURLOPT_URL        => $endpoint_url,
CURLOPT_POST       => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_to_post,`enter code here`
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> false
];


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);


curl_exec($curl);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl));
curl_close($curl);
```

And it only returns HTTP400 badrequest. what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: localhost or LIVE server?

Comment: I tested it live and localhost. both didnt work

Comment: you probably should be sending `json_encode($data_to_post)` , not `$data_to_post` ... just a WAG but would be coherent with many API's.

Comment: that was the fix.... i feel stupid now

Answer (score 2):

Try to encode the data using `json_encode`:

```
$data_to_post  = json_encode([
    'dev_id' => 'mydevice',
    'port' => 1,
    'confirmed' => false,
    'payload_raw' => 'MDA=']);
```